# What are all the URIs paths for windowsdefender://threat?

Tags: windows, windows-11, shortcuts

I wanted to create a shortcut to directly get to the specific windows settings page where I can turn off the "real-time protection" temporarily.

[image]

There seems to be a `windowsdefender://threat` shortcut which is close enough, just leaves me one click away from where I want to be.

So I wondered if this URI scheme actually allows to get to my originally intended page, and what would be the path for that setting?

I can't seem to find any documentation on what all paths `windowsdefender://xxx` has, except a few pop up in the dropdown list when creating shortcuts:

[image]

The few options that pop up seem to indicate a rich structure to the paths and query strings that might allow to reach deep pages with a single shortcut.

So my question is, can someone provide information on all the available shortcuts and paths within the `windowsdefender://xxx` scheme?

And is there one that reaches the "Real-time protection" settings page directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good updated list of the URLs here, but they change as windows defender updates, so not all of the ones listed are still available: https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-security-windowsdefender-urls/

The direct shortcut to the page in your screenshot is `windowsdefender://threatsettings/`

There's also a shortcut to re-enable protection directly: `windowsdefender://enablertp`

Answer (score 2):

You may use PowerShell to disable and enable Microsoft Defender
real-time protection.

To disable :

```
Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true
```

To enable :

```
Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $false
```